# Is it possible to send mail on behalf of a user with the gmail API

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) to send mail from gmail with a service account. My understanding is that we should be able to delegate to any account under the domain, but when I try to send from any other sender I get errors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-do-i-get-rid-of-on-behalf-of-from-my-sent-gmail-messages) shows that this is doable but using the manual mode. I haven't seen an implementation using the Gmail API yet.